# What should I wish for?

Tags: merry-clickmas

The Christmas tree is asking me to choose a wish. I can choose a multiplier or more wishes. What's the best option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The choose more wishes wish simply generates a new wish in its place and lets you wish again.  You won't get duplicate wishes though.

If you like the multiplier on offer a lot, you should take the multiplier and leave the free wish for when the generated wish is something you don't want.

If you don't want the multiplier on offer, take the free wish and it will give you a different option.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not in the Christmas multipliers get but, here's a strategy.

Option 1:I think you should get multipliers and when your done you can go back on getting wishes.

Option 2 (I think I prefer this one better):Maybe you can just buy a multiplier and then after make a wish and then alternate it.